# Associate File Extension with Application fail with long file names

Tags: associations, filenames, long-integer

I have a project that is named : "Testing results". It generates a executable "Testing results".
If I try to setup my info.plist file to have an association with files received by mail, the mail program doesn't recognize it.
This is my info.plist:

```
CFBundleDevelopmentRegion
en
CFBundleDisplayName
${PRODUCT_NAME}
CFBundleDocumentTypes


        CFBundleTypeIconFiles

            Sandbox-icon.png

        CFBundleTypeName
        dep
        CFBundleTypeRole
        Viewer
        LSHandlerRank
        Default
        LSItemContentTypes

            araferna.${EXECUTABLE_NAME}.dep



CFBundleExecutable
${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
CFBundleIdentifier
araferna.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion
6.0
CFBundleName
${PRODUCT_NAME}
CFBundlePackageType
APPL
CFBundleShortVersionString
1.0
CFBundleSignature
????
CFBundleVersion
1.0
LSRequiresIPhoneOS
<true/>
UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

    armv7

UISupportedInterfaceOrientations

    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight

UTExportedTypeDeclarations


        UTTypeConformsTo

            public.data

        UTTypeDescription
        Testing Results Document
        UTTypeIdentifier
        araferna.${EXECUTABLE_NAME}.dep
        UTTypeTagSpecification

            public.filename-extension
            dep
            public.mime-type
            application/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
```

I have another project with the same contents and the same info.list only I called it "Testing " and it works well. I guess the association doesn't take long file names with " "(spaces).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution was create a short name(no spaces or forbidden chr) for my product name (that generates my executable name).
It works fine now. But I wanted to keep my long name that is more meaningful!!!
So the question-assertion remains open...
If any solutions, please, tell me.
Thanks.